# Using numpy mgrid with a variable number of indices

Tags: python, numpy

How do you use numpy.mgrid with a variable number of indices? I can't find any examples on github of anyone using this with anything but hardcoded values.

```
import numpy as np
np.mgrid[1:10, 1:10] # this works fine

x = (1, 10)
np.mgrid[x[0]:x[1], x[0]:x[1]] # hardcoded

xs = [(1,10)] * 10
np.mgrid[*xs????] # I can't get anything to work here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
np.mgrid[[slice(i,j) for i,j in [(1,10)]*10]]
```

though with `*10` it is too large

It's derived from that fact

```
np.mgrid[slice(1,10),slice(1,10)]  # same as
np.mgrid[1:10,1:10]
```

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the notation in your last line is just "syntactic sugar" to create the slice objects?

Comment: Great, thanks! Never had the occasion to use slice() before, nice.

Comment: Yes, the Python interpreter converts the `[x:y:z]` to a slice object.  https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slice#slicings