# How do I insert variable step into Numpy mgrid?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpy.mgrid to create two grid arrays, but I want a way to insert a variable as the number of steps.

Without a variable number of steps, numpy.mgrid works as expected with this code:

```
x, y = np.mgrid[0:1:3j, 0:2:5j]
```

But, what I want is something like this, because I am not able to explicitly state my step number in the line of code to generate the grid arrays (the values may change due to other processes in my script):

```
num_x_steps = 3
num_y_steps = 5
x, y = np.mgrid[0:1:(num_x_steps)j, 0:2:(num_y_steps)j] #Try convert to complex
```

Is there a way to do that, that returns a result equivalent to the first method?

I tried running my 3-line code with and without parentheses and tried a couple other modifications, but nothing seemed to work.

NOTE: I tried reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685802/using-numpy-mgrid-with-a-variable-number-of-indices) topic, but I am not sure if what that topic deals with is applicable to this problem; I don't quite understand what is being asked or how it was answered.  (Also, I tried running the line of code from the answer, and it returned a MemoryError.)  If said topic does answer my problem, could someone please explain it better, and how it applies to my problem?

Comment: The use of `3j` in `mgrid` is a notational trick.  Internally it checks if the slice step is complex (mathematically imaginary), and does some math that treats it as a count rather than the usual `arange` step size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The glitch is that `j` following parentheses doesn't convert to a complex number.

```
In [41]:(1)j
  File "<ipython-input-41-874f75f848c4>", line 1
    (1)j
       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Multiplying a value by `1j` will work, and these lines give `x, y` equivalent to your first line:

```
num_x_steps = 3
num_y_steps = 5
x, y = np.mgrid[0:1:(num_x_steps * 1j), 0:2:(num_y_steps * 1j)]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is to convert the num of steps to a complex number.

```
num_x_steps = 3
x_steps = complex(str(num_x_steps) + "j")

num_y_steps = 5
y_steps = complex(str(num_y_steps) + "j")

x, y = np.mgrid[0:1:x_steps, 0:2:y_steps]
```